# Problems with insertion of numbers in mysql with europe style

Tags: mysql, insert

I'm trying to insert some information I'm taking from a different website using method crawl.

The number are shown as : 1.658.056 or 12.423.589 with two dots, so i need to add this field and i cant with that double dots.

This is the table where i save the information:

```
Create table IF NOT EXISTS LJugador(
Fecha date,
vm float(10,6),
nom_jugador varchar(80),
FOREIGN KEY (nom_jugador) REFERENCES Jugadores(nombre),
PRIMARY KEY(Fecha, nom_jugador)
```

I save the information inside of my field vm - float(10,6).

For example if I put 1.230.000 in database is saved as: 1.230000, but when I try to add this amount with another for example 160.000 its give me a result of 161.620000 so I don't know how to make it, and is back me crazy, seriously.

Comment: Don't use the players name as the primary/foreign key.

Comment: Are they still strings? "1.230.000" you need to parse them in to a decimal type first, or cast / convert them with the correct format in the sql. Worst case rip the dots out as they are thousand seperators at a guess.

Answer (score 0):

The `FLOAT(10,6)` will yield something like: `IIII.FFFFFF` - where both `I` and `F` are integers.

Obviously, the solution is to remove the localized dots before inserting the record - it's trivial.